# remove certain entries from xml file using notepad++

Tags: xml

I had a sample file. I want to remove entries that start with '" in the huge excel file fully. I want to removed all the comment.

for example in below sample I want to remove

```
<!--General Language-->
```

and

```
<!--Disable-->
```

How I can use regular expression in notepad++?

```
`<attributes>
<LANNO>0</LANNO><!--General Language-->
<VERSION>DOPRA_C V100R007</VERSION>
</attributes>
<attributes>
<ENABLEFLAG>0</ENABLEFLAG><!--Disable-->
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set "Search Mode" to "Regular Expression" and then use the following pattern:

```
<!--.*-->
```

The pattern matches a start comment (`<!--`) followed by *any number of characters* and ended by an end comment (`-->`).

Answer (score 0):

Do below steps-

1- Ctrl+H (It will open replace window)

2- Then search for your text, In your example

3- Replace with \1

4- Make sure the mode "Regular expressions" is selected.

5. Click on Replace all.